# Nested Class in Swift

Tags: json, xcode, swift, class

I have problem with swift.

I have 2 class in city.swift file like this:

```
import Foundation

class Place {
    var name : String!
    var tel : String!
    var kind : String!
}

class City {
    var name : String!
    var describe : String!

    var hotel : Place!

    init(data: NSDictionary)
    {
        self.name = data["name"] as? String
        self.describe = data["city_description"] as? String
        self.hotel = data["hotelName"] as? Place
    }
}
```

I parse information from JSON file.
my problem is when I try to get cities.hotel with this code:

```
if let items = json["cities"] as? NSArray {
        for item in items {
              let place = Place()
              let cities = City(data: item as! NSDictionary)
                   println("\(cities.hotel)")
              }
         }
```

Xcode return me "nil" but city.name and city.describe work fine. why?
thanks for help.

EDIT:
this my obj-c code and work fine :

City.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *describe;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Place *hotel;
```

Place.h

```
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSString *address;
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSString *tel;
```

collectionView.m

```
    _jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:fileData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
_citiesListArray = [_jsonData objectForKey:@"cities"];

_citySingleList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *cityDictionary in _citiesListArray) {

    City *city = [[City alloc] init];

    city.name = [cityDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
    city.describe = [cityDictionary objectForKey:@"city_description"];

    city.hotel = [cityDictionary objectForKey:@"hotels"];

    NSLog(@"%@", city.hotel);

}
```

and JSON file

```
 "cities": [
    {
        "name": "City Name",
        "city_description" : "City Describe",
        "hotels": [
            {
                "name" : "Hotel Name",
                "tel" : "Hotel Tel",
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

when I NSLog city.hotel in obj-c return me

```
{
    "name" : "Hotel Name",
    "tel" : "Hotel Tel",
},
```

but my Swift code return nil, where I make mistake? thanks for help again

P.S hotel property is a subclass of Place class. because I want to use that like this later :

```
city.hotel.name = hotelDictionery["name"]
```

Comment: Why force unwrapped properties? And you need to parse you hotel out of the JSON.

Comment: @Abizern I edited the answer.

Comment: Please don't abuse implicitly unwrapped optionals like this.  Unfortunately for the rest of the Swift world, someone besides you will probably eventually end up maintaining this code.

Comment: @Abizern I edited it again.

Comment: I don't get the relation between title and content of the question. it is just another 'I can't parse json' problem... the question isn't clear and concise and so I am voting to close

Comment: You still aren't parsing the Place dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

As I've already said in the comments, you aren't parsing the hotel. So, here is a complete example that you can put into a playground and verify for yourself

Requires Xcode 7 and Swift 2

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

// This is a Dictionary representation of your JSON for a single element
let item: [String : AnyObject] = [
    "name" : "City Name",
    "city_description" : "City Describe",
    "hotels": [
        "name" : "Hotel Name",
        "tel" : "Hotel Tel",
    ]
]

// Here is your Place value as a strict, which is the way I would write it

struct Place {
    let name: String
    let tel: String
    let kind: String
}

// Put custom initialisers in an extension. That way, the default initialiser is provided by the system
extension Place {
    // The initialiser takes a dictionary that gets the values from the dictionary,
    // filling in missing values with empty strings
    init(dictionary: [String : AnyObject]) {
        self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String ?? ""
        self.tel = dictionary["tel"] as? String ?? ""
        self.kind = dictionary["kind"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}

// Here is your City value as a struct, which is the way I would write it

struct City {
    let name: String
    let describe: String
    let hotel: Place

}

extension City {
    // The initialiser takes a dictionary that gets the values from the item dictionary,
    // missing values are provided as empty strings
    init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
        self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String ?? ""
        self.describe = dictionary["city_description"] as? String ?? ""

        if let hotels = dictionary["hotels"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
            self.hotel = Place(dictionary: hotels)
        } else {
            self.hotel = Place(name: "Default name", tel: "Default tel", kind: "Default kind")
        }
    }
}

// Now parse the item

let city = City(dictionary: item)
```

And for me, this gives the output:

[image]